# Why is packagekit starting up throughout the day

Tags: 12.04, gnome, apt, software-center

Why is packagekit starting up throughout the day? There is no
indication in the messages which component is sending the message to
start packagekit, just a dbus message indicating that the service
was started:

```
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS"
```

---

```
Syslog 

AptDaemon.PackageKit: INFO: Initializing PackageKit compat layer
dbus[1207]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit'
AptDaemon.PackageKit: INFO: Initializing PackageKit transaction
AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Simulating trans: /org/debian/apt/transaction/fbf7b3e9013a4a94a9bcf7a178f1d31e
AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Processing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/fbf7b3e9013a4a94a9bcf7a178f1d31e
```

Answer (score 3):

That isn't `PackageKit`, but rather is a compatible API in `aptdaemon` such that things written with the `PackageKit` API to request installation of packages, and do so on Ubuntu, without having to support a different API.

If you look at `/var/log/apt/history.log` and find the correlating time for when this call happened, you should be able to see what the transaction was at least. If there is no correlating activity in there, it's likely something requesting a check for updates available to the system.

You could use the `dbus-monitor` tool in a terminal, filtering on the `org.freedesktop.PackageKit` service, to see what is making the call.